# integrate yodlee fastlink on mobile platforms

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to integrate Yodlee Fastlink on Android and IOS platforms. But could not get a mobile-optimized view. Is there any argument needed to pass (e.g. there is a displayMode argument, but not mentioned which values can be specified) ?

According to http://blog.yodleeinteractive.com/three-changes-to-fastlink-how-to-optimize-your-mobile-app-experience/  'Yodlee FastLink now supports user experiences on iOS and Android platforms'.

Answer (score 3):

The mobile compatible FastLink is still not available for all the customers and it's in beta phase , You can have access to it once it's available to all after the beta phase. Please reach out to your customer success manager to get more info on this.

Comment: has this been released yet?